# Validate Pojo's in OSGi

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I would validate my anootated pojos (JSR 303) with the HibernateValidator in my OSGi.
The unit Tests works fine but on the OSGi it doesn't work.

Here's my Validator Method:

```
public static void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().providerResolver(new OSGiServiceDiscoverer()).configure()
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validatorResult = null;

    if (o instanceof MessageContentsList) {
        MessageContentsList messageList = (MessageContentsList) o;
        validatorResult = validator.validate(messageList.get(0));
    } else {
        validatorResult = validator.validate(o);
    }

    if (!validatorResult.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (ConstraintViolation<Object> v : validatorResult) {
            sb.append(v.getPropertyPath() + " " + v.getMessage() + ", ");
        }

        String msg = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1);

        throw new ValidationException(msg);
    }
}
```

And here the Discoverer:

```
public class OSGiServiceDiscoverer implements ValidationProviderResolver {

    @Override
    public List<ValidationProvider<?>> getValidationProviders() {
        List<ValidationProvider<?>> providers = new ArrayList<ValidationProvider<?>>(1);
        providers.add(new HibernateValidator());
        return providers;
    }
}
```

In the pom I've added the following imports for the OSGi:

```
javax.validation,
javax.validation.bootstrap,
javax.validation.constraints,
javax.validation.spi,
org.hibernate.validator,
```

Has someone a idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thx

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work' exactly?

Comment: I manipulate the request, so it is not valid. But the validatorResult are emtpy when i debug in the osgi. In the unit test it works and has the failed messages are in it for the same message

Comment: I've made a test class who prints out all annotations from the field. In the unit test all JSR303 Annotations are present and on the OSGi they arent present.
I hope someone can help me with that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution by myself.
The reason was, that the annotated classes were in a seperate bundle than the validation and there I haven't add the javax.validation dependencies. So the Annotations were ignored and the validation has no functionality